# c# why is my coroutine Executing only once regardless of condition for while loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to execute a coroutine which destroys from a queue of gameobjects with a pause in between each execution until the Queue of game objects has been cleared, I have tried putting it in the start function and the update function and both give the same results of it only running once. coroutine works fine without clearDestroyStack function.

All the code is in a script attached to the game objects that are in the queue.

This is the call

```
if (lightningListFilled) {
        StartCoroutine ("clearLighteningTargets");
        lightningListFilled = false;
    }
    else {
    }
```

The following is the coroutine.

```
IEnumerator clearLighteningTargets(){
    while (lighteningDestroyList.Count > 0) {
        Debug.Log ("From clear: "+lighteningDestroyList.Count);
        refScript.destroyStack.Push (lighteningDestroyList.Dequeue ());
        refScript.clearDestroyStack ();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
        Debug.Log ("From clear: "+lighteningDestroyList.Count);

    }
}
```

this is the code for the clearDestroyStack function

```
public void clearDestroyStack (){
    while (destroyStack.Count != 0) {
        GameObject ballToDestroy = destroyStack.Pop ();
        List<GameObject> ballToDestroyParents = ballToDestroy.GetComponent<MoveToCenter> ().parents;
        List<GameObject> ballToDestroyChildren = ballToDestroy.GetComponent<MoveToCenter> ().children;
        foreach (GameObject parent in ballToDestroyParents) {
            if (parent != null) {
                if (parent.GetComponent<MoveToCenter> ().children.Contains (ballToDestroy)) {
                    parent.GetComponent<MoveToCenter> ().children.Remove (ballToDestroy);
                }   
            }

        }
        foreach (GameObject child in ballToDestroyChildren) {
            if (child != null) {
                if (child.GetComponent<MoveToCenter> ().parents.Contains (ballToDestroy)) {
                    child.GetComponent<MoveToCenter> ().parents.Remove (ballToDestroy);
                }
            }

        }
        GameObject[] allBalls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("ball");


        foreach (GameObject ball in allBalls) {
            ball.GetComponent<MoveToCenter> ().isSafe = false;
        }
        Destroy (ballToDestroy);
        //startSafeScan ();
        //deleteUnsafeBalls ();
        //clearDestroyStack ();
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1.Show us how you are calling the `clearLighteningTargets` coroutine. 2.Show how the `lighteningDestroyList` is being cleared.

Comment: are you getting an error? maybe clearDestroyStack has an error and crashes the script

Comment: @Lestat No there are no errors displayed

Comment: What is the output of your program? I mean, what are the values in the console log.. Specifically those lines Debug.Log ("From clear: "...)... ??

Comment: what game object is this script attached to?

Comment: What is your code meant to do? Remove a gameobject?

Comment: @mayo the first Debug.Log ("From clear: "+lighteningDestroyList.Count); will show  the count of the queue, the second Debug.Log ("From clear: "+lighteningDestroyList.Count); doesnt print.

Comment: Coroutines stop if the object they are attached to is destroyed.

Comment: @LeoBartkus seems to have the answer to your question! Also I think that you can design a way to remove elements in a more clean. (like just one script, in parent object that runs a removal coroutine of queued elements)

Comment: Yup. That was the issue. I took out the destroy code from game object script and put it in a script attached to empty game object. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines stop if the object they are attached to is destroyed.